# how to show this function doesn't belong to Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

I am trying to show $\chi_{B_R(0)}(x) \notin H^1 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ , ∀R>0.

since $H^1 (\mathbb{R}^n) := W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

That is, I have to show that $\chi_{B_R(0)}  (x) \notin L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\nexists g_1,g_2....g_n \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that

$-\int_{B_R(0)} \chi_{B_R(0)}(x) \frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x_i} dx= \int_{B_R(0)} \phi(x) g_i(x) dx, \forall \phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. any ideas..

Comment: The issue is with the derivative in $H^1$, clearly the characteristic function is in $L^2$

Comment: I am thinking that the characteristic function of the ball of radius R, is not in L^2. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, the characteristic function picks out the volume of a ball of radius $R$ in $L^2$. If $R$ is finite, there is finite volume. Therefore $|| \chi ||_2 < \infty \implies \chi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the derivative of a step function? Is it a function? Can a functional act on a functional?

Example: Look at $\chi_{[-R,R]}$ for $\mathbb{R}$.

Clearly $ \chi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, since

$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \chi_{[-R,R]}^2 dx = \int_{-R}^R dx = 2R < \infty$$

But what about $\partial_x \chi$ ?

$$\int_\mathbb{R} (\partial_x \chi )^2 dx = \chi \partial_x \chi \big |_\mathbb{R} - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi \partial_x^2 \chi dx = \chi \underbrace{\partial_x \chi }_{\delta \, like}\big |_\mathbb{R}- \int_{-R}^R \partial_x^2 \chi dx  = \infty$$

Therefore $\chi \not \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$